# Keymap option missing Next TODO

Tags: intellij-idea, key-bindings, todo

I'm trying to add a keybinding for `Next TODO`

I see this option in two places:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> TODO section / down arrow on the left
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> actions menu (search "next todo")

What I'm trying to do is to add a keymap under keymap section, but as you can see on the below screenshot there is no option when searching for **next todo**
[image]

Can anyone help?
In case its a bug, I have submitted a bug on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-241232)

In case it helps my IntelliJ/System details:
IU-193.7288.26, JRE 11.0.6+8-b520.66x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Linux(amd64) v5.4.0-29-generic, Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Use "Next Occurrence" and "Previous Occurrence" actions:

[image]

Comment: This implies I'm already on a TODO. What I need is a key binding to find the next TODO no matter where my cursor is on the file.

Comment: There was an issue that has been fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230766